# same command renders different output in terminal vs. PyCharm Python 3.7.3 on WIndows 10?

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, subprocess, windows-10-desktop

I want to execute this command:
`powershell.exe -Command "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | Sort DisplayName -Unique"`
using Python 3.7.3 in Pycharm IDE.  I get different results if i cut and paste that same command in Terminal, even terminal within Pycharm IDE will produce the correct results:

```
DisplayName                                                                         DisplayVersion     Publisher
-----------                                                                         --------------     ---------

Avatier Credential Provider                                                         10.6.18080         Avatier Corporation
Avatier SetUpCachedCred 64-bit                                                      1.0.6              Avatier
.....
```

but running the framework, executing that same command either via os.system(cmd) or subprocess.Popen(...), subprocess.check_output(...), i get different results like so:

```
DisplayName                                                        DisplayVersion   Publisher                        
-----------                                                        --------------   ---------                        

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC                                            20.006.20042     Adobe Systems Incorporated       
Adobe Refresh Manager                                              1.8.0            Adobe Systems Incorporated       
BootRacer 7.90                                                     7.90             Greatis Software                 
Carbon Black Sensor                                                6.2.2.90503      Carbon Black, Inc.
...
```

This is on the same physical machine, Windows 10, 1909 build.
Please help with workaround and/or solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that, in spite of what you think, you're not actually executing the command where you think you are.

When I run this:

```
import subprocess

args = [
    r'powershell.exe',
    r'-Command',
    r'Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | Sort DisplayName -Unique'
]

result = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True)

print(result.stdout.decode('windows-1252'))
```

(either from PyCharm, or from the command line with `python test.py`)

I get a next to identical result to when running this:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | Sort DisplayName -Unique"
```

(directly from the command line)

The only real difference is in line endings, but that's not your problem.

Comment: I got difference results between your code and your command line command above?  they are not matching.  I tried to cut and paste, but its too large.

Comment: from your code: DisplayName                                                        DisplayVersion   Publisher                        
-----------                                                        --------------   ---------                        
                                                                                                                     
Adobe Acrobat Reader DC                                            20.006.20042     Adobe Systems Incorporated

Comment: from your command line: powershell.exe -Command "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | Sort DisplayName -Unique"

DisplayName                                                                         DisplayVersion     Publisher
-----------                                                                         --------------     ---------
Avatier Credential Provider                                                         10.6.18080         Avatier ...

Comment: I suppose what this "answer" tells you that the problem you are describing cannot be replicated without also adjusting something else relevant that you're not sharing here. Just to be sure I tried on a couple of different machines, Win 10 Home, Win 10 Pro, Server 2012 R2 - all with the same outcome, no differences other than line endings. Also not sure how the example I provided would be too large for you to copy and paste... It seems the problems you are having aren't exactly where you think they may be.

Comment: My coworker is seeing the exact problem.  I am not imaginging this.  I've tried os.system, subprocess.run, subprocess.check_output, subprocess.Popen, all produced consistently wrong answer from simply running the command in terminal and/or powershell?  There were host of similar questions on StackOverflow i see.  FYI, i am using Python 3.7.3 32 bit on Windows 10, 1909 package.  Unless its something related to security policy with company's laptop, that prevent me from running python script to execute PowerShell?  I know old Powershell ISE with the UI, woudn't allow my sign in to run scripts.

Comment: Sorry, did not want to imply you were imagining things - however, in multiple situations, I am unable to reproduce your results, based on what you've told us so far. In fact, when I do what you say you're doing, it's working as you expected it to work - not as you say it is working on your end. That's why I provided exactly the code that works for me, so you can try exactly that, instead of assuming it's the same. But then you complained about it being too large to copy and paste, which seems to suggest you're doing something very odd...

Comment: Further narrowing down of the issue points to how Python are calling the subprocess or invoking the os.system.  Something changed by the time Powershell gets the command to execute?  But, running same command in Terminal, yielded the correct result.  Its a wild goose chase as there are hundreds of failed solutions on StackOverflow. They ought to clean things up, because solutions 10 years ago are no longer working in today's version of Python.

Comment: "They" = "you" on a community-driven platform like SO. Nobody here is being paid to write or maintain content and SO themselves are just there to keep the platform running. If you see a solution that no longer works, you can just post a comment stating what version of Python you tried it on and that it doesn't work - the poster of the answer can then either update the answer, or make it specific to versions of Python that do work. However - Python has pretty good backward compatibility and in this case, it's more likely that other factors are causing trouble.